# Decidability of model of set theory.

Tags: logic

I am wondering if there exists a model of set theory (KPU or ZFC) that has decidable theory?

Thanks.

Comment: Such a model will be able to solve the halting problem.

Comment: what do you mean by a model having a decidable theorem?

Comment: I mean , is there a model of set theory for which we can design an algorithm to decide all the first order formula sastified in it .... Thanks , obviously I am not talking here about all theorem of the structure ...

Comment: Do you have the references of the work you mentionned of David Harris ? Please...

Comment: @Dehn: I believe that Peter Smith is talking about David Harris's answer below.

Comment: @Peter Smith: Please see my comment below the answer by David Harris.

Comment: Ok thank you very much guys, I have now understood what I was doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: [My comment deleted -- at least until I've had time to rethink in the light of Carl Mummert's comments below.]

Answer (score 4):

Any model of set theory includes the full true theory of arithmetic. Even very weak theories of arithmetic, let alone the full True Arithmetic, are undecidable.

Comment: That, and we don't even know for sure if there exists *any* model of ZFC. :)

Comment: Any reasonable model of set theory, anyway... (Even models of finite set theory can be undecidable – ZFC minus Infinity and Peano arithmetic are biinterpretable, for example.)

Comment: An arbitrary model could have nonstandard natural numbers and so the set of arithmetical formulas that is true in that model could be very different than the true theory of arithmetic. Naively, that set could even be computable. So it is not enough to note that the set of true arithmetic sentences is not computable. ...

Comment: However, the answer can be remedied via Tennenbaum's theorem that no nonstandard model of PA has a computable elementary diagram (neither addition nor multiplication can be computable). Because the theory of each model of ZFC computes the theory of a model of PA, if the model of ZFC is not an $\omega$-model this shows its theory cannot be computable. Or you could use the fact that the theory of the model of ZFC computes a completion of PA, and no such extension is computable (even if it is nonstandard). But it takes more than the uncomputablity of true arithmetic, in any case.

Answer (score 2):

The viewpoint that is usually taken in the literature is to look at extensions of the original theory rather than models of it. A theory is said to be **essentially incomplete** if it has no decidable complete consistent extension.  Essential incompleteness implies, in particular, that the theory cannot have a model whose elementary diagram is decidable.

A corollary of the incompleteness theorems is that many effective theories are essentially incomplete. For example, Peano arithmetic and ZFC are both essentially incomplete, so they cannot have models whose elementary diagrams are decidable.

On the other hand, the theory of groups is incomplete, because it cannot prove or disprove $(\exists x)(\exists y)(x \not = y)$, but it can be made complete by adding the axiom $(\forall x)(\forall y)(x = y)$, and the resulting theory (which is categorical) has a model whose elementary diagram is decidable.